# How to make a method GET with parameters and a uri at the end?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api

I have an API with I have to make a get call with parameters and a URI at the end, but I don't know how,

I have already done a method, I am missing the end

API : http://henri-potier.xebia.fr/books

my question is how to make a method so that the result gives this,

API with parameter : [http://henri-potier.xebia.fr/books/{ISBN1](http://henri-potier.xebia.fr/books/%7BISBN1), ISBN2, ...}/commercialOffers

**Service**

```
  getBook(): Observable<posts> {
    let param = new HttpParams().set('isbn', '');
    return this.http.get<posts>(this.url, {params:param});
  }
```

**interface posts**

```
export interface posts {

    isbn: string;
    title: string;
    price: number;
    cover:string;
    synopsis:string;
}
```

[image]

Comment: How does the end result look like?

Comment: Api with parameter final result of the get method, I will update with the final result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use variable path parameters in your api in the first place.

Instead of "/books/{ISBN1, ISBN2, ...}/commercialOffers" consider using "/books/commercialOffers" and pass "isbn" as query parameter (not path parameter);

Then you could pass an isbn query parameter as a list :

```js
let param = new HttpParams().set('isbn', ['un', 'deux', 'trois']);
```

That should produce a query param like : "?isbn=un,deux,trois"

EDIT: if you absolutely want to keep the API as is, you will have to build the url :

```
let url = apiUrl + '/books/' + isbnList.join(',') + '/commercialOffers'
```

Comment: i have this error when i try your code : let param = new HttpParams().set('isbn', ['un', 'deux', 'trois']);  Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)

Comment: just use [].join(',') then, but if you do not decide how the API is made use the second method. HttpParams is made to build query parameters not path parameters

Comment: isbnList I have to create it how ?

Comment: just `const isbnList = ['isbn1', 'isbn2']`